# Why does the dope sheet use (inconsistent) white for unselected / deselected?

Tags: selection-tools, color, dopesheet

Why does the dope sheet window in Blender uses a solid white color to indicate that a keyframe is **not** selected and a color (depends on your Blender theme which color e.g. orange) to represent that the keyframe **is** selected?

I'd like to know why the dope sheet uses the opposite to convention to the 3D view (which uses white to show a selected vertex). It seems inconsistent to me. Knowing why this is should help me to remember whether I have a keyframe selected or not. Currently, I have to remind myself which way round it is by pressing 'A' a few times to select all and deselect all.

Comment: [By default](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/dope_sheet/introduction.html#main-region) Blender uses grey color for unselected keyframes and white (previously orange) for unselected keyframes. The color theme doesn't correlate with viewport (which is orange for selected) but the logic by default is the same.

Comment: What I'm trying to find out is why it is inconsistent with vertex selection in the 3D view. I don't understand why a bright color is used for selection and a dark color is used for deselection with vertices (also edges, faces, and bones) but with keyframe selection it's the opposite! It's very confusing if you work with both modeling and animation. YouTube tutorials I've been watching have also pointed out this confusing inconsistency.

Answer (score 3):

It is set that way as they are the colours that were chosen.

You can change both selected and deselected colours in the theme settings if you feel other colours work better. We can't set a transparency with the keyframes but if you set it the same as the background colour then only the border is seen to make it appear hollow. The keyframe border below the keyframe colours is the outline of the marker.

[image: dopesheet theme settings]

Comment: Thanks! I've switched those colors so for your theme Keyframe would be orange and Keyframe Selected would be white. This now matches the 3D view where a bright color always indicates a selected vertex. I just still can't understand why the designers have chosen to use a bright color for deselected and a (non-bright) color for selected!

Answer (score 1):

for me the dope sheet colors are the same as in the viewport. Orange is selected and white is unselected. In the viewport as well but there is thge white color showing that the object is moving (Or currently in edit) and if the object is not selected its not showing any border. You couldnt have no border (fill) in the dope sheet because the you know you wont see anything